# Extract few characters from a string

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I'm trying to find out a way to extract few characters from a string(Column) which starts with a keyword and ends with '.net'

**String**:

```
Source: epw050015.catxtx.net
Description: vCenter: 198.11.12.98
alarm.NetworkConnectivityLostAlarm - Event: Lost Network Connectivity (11355590)
Summary: Lost network connectivity on virtual switch  vSwitchiDRACvusb . Physical NIC vusb0 is down. Affected portgroups: iDRAC Network .
Date: 02/06/19 12:28:04
Host: epw050015.catxtx.net
Resource pool: W05P006 (6.5) GAD
Data center: W05
```

From the above string; I'm trying to extract characters that appears after "**Host:**" til **".net"**

Output should be: `epw050015.catxtx.net`

**Note**: In the string there are instances when values after Host: might have more than one/two space. An example - Host:       epw050015.catxtx.net

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: select substr
('Source: epw050015.catxtx.net Description: vCenter: 198.11.12.98 alarm.NetworkConnectivityLostAlarm - Event: Lost Network Connectivity (11355590) Summary: Lost network connectivity on virtual switch vSwitchiDRACvusb . Physical NIC vusb0 is down. Affected portgroups: iDRAC Network . Date: 02/06/19 12:28:04 Host: epw050015.catxtx.net Resource pool: W05P006 (6.5) GAD Data center: W05',
INSTR('Host:     ltdevmq01.bmwgroup.net Service:  os_linux_default_check_shell',' ',1)+1) 
from dual;

This is what I was able to come up with.

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
SELECT 'Source: epw050015.catxtx.net
Description: vCenter: 198.11.12.98
alarm.NetworkConnectivityLostAlarm - Event: Lost Network Connectivity (11355590)
Summary: Lost network connectivity on virtual switch  vSwitchiDRACvusb . Physical NIC vusb0 is down. Affected portgroups: iDRAC Network .
Date: 02/06/19 12:28:04
Host: epw050015.catxtx.net
Resource pool: W05P006 (6.5) GAD
Data center: W05' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

Find the index of the end of the `Host:` substring (at the start of a line) within the text and then find the index of the subsequent line feed and then get the sub-string between the two:

```sql
SELECT TRIM( SUBSTR( value, start_host, end_host - start_host ) ) AS host
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         INSTR( value, CHR(10)||'Host:' ) + 6 AS start_host,
         INSTR( value, CHR(10), INSTR( value, CHR(10)||'Host:' ) + 6 ) AS end_host
  FROM   test_data
)
```

**Query 2**:

Or you can use a regular expression, which may be a slower solution but the code is simpler:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '^Host:\s+(.*?)$', 1, 1, 'm', 1 ) AS host
FROM   test_data
```

**Output**:

Both solutions output:

> ```
> | HOST                 |
> | :------------------- |
> | epw050015.catxtx.net |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b402c214c0e43908fc83f51432de6d77)*

Comment: Thanks, MT0. Query 2 seems to do the trick. Let me implement this in my query; I will get back to you as early as possible with an update.

Comment: Here's one scenario where output fetches extra work

Column Value:

Host: liapp419vm.catxtx.net ERROR:

qqosm00@liapp419vm:/www/osmaster> ./GFserver4 stop -i 0

Output: liapp419vm.bmwgroup.net ERROR:

Comment: @Praveen Please don't post data as comments (especially if it is supposed to have line-breaks), instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58955468/edit) your question and use the `{}` code markup to clarify your question. Preferably add the data as DML statements that we can run them and easily work out what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTR(COLUM_NAME, INSTR(COLUM_NAME,'Host:') + LENGTH('Host:'), INSTR(COLUM_NAME,'.net') - INSTR(COLUM_NAME,'Host:') - LENGTH('Host:') + LENGTH('.net'))) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

You can see it in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9f207/4/0

This finds the string between the *position* of `Host:` and *position + length('.net')* of `.net`. And then `TRIM` function to remove any spaces at the side as you said there might be more than a single space after `Host:`

Comment: This is fine if the `Host:` line is always immediately followed by the `Resource pool:` line but it will not work if the `Host:` and `Resource pool:` lines are swapped or if the `Resource pool:` line is missing for certain error messages or if there is another line introduced between the two or if the string `Resource` appears anywhere else earlier in the text.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I modified the code, so now it works without `Resource` word. @MT0

Comment: Thanks, @Hackinet for your inputs :)

Tried implementing what you suggested in my query; it extracts the required characters correctly however in few scenarios it doesn't work.

Scenario 1: 

Column Value (1)

vCenter: 160.96.181.43
TargetObject: epmuc0416.catxtx.net
alarm.NetworkRedundancyLostAlarm - Event: Lost Network Redundancy (83327966)
Date: 11/12/19 14:15:16
Host: epmuc0416.catxtx.net
Resource pool: MUCP095 (6.5) GAD
Data center: MUC

Output ---<blank>

Comment: Scenario 2: If the column value contains .net however the keyword 'Host:' does not exist

Column Value (2):
We have recived multiple Incident for the below hosts due to load issues:
Please check the issue for below host too:
lpapp144.catxtx.net 
lpapp149.catxtx.net 
lpapp153.catxtx.net

Output - We have recived multiple Incident for the below hosts due to load issues:
Please check the issue for below host too:
lpapp144.catxtx.net